# joining absolute and relative URLs of sharepoint in <a href> anchor tag

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, spweb, anchor-tags, spurl

I want to join absolute and relative URL parts of a sharepoint site in `<a href="http://somesite">` tag.

i already have this:

```
strng.Format(@"<a href=""/_layouts/something/Mypage.aspx?workflowID={0}"">{1}</a>", workflowguid, ItemRow["Title"].ToString());
```

I want to add absolute URL part like this:

```
strng.Format(@"<a href=""SPContext.Current.Web.Url/_layouts/something/Mypage.aspx?workflowID={0}"">{1}</a>", workflowguid, ItemRow["Title"].ToString());
```

But, its incorrect, it considers "SPContext.Current.Web.Url" as series of characters, I want output should be like this:

```
strng.Format(@"<a href=""http://Mysite.com/_layouts/something/Mypage.aspx?workflowID={0}"">{1}</a>", workflowguid, ItemRow["Title"].ToString());
```

How i fix this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what your looking for ;)

```
strng.Format(@"<a href="""+SPContext.Current.Web.Url+"/_layouts/something/Mypage.aspx?workflowID={0}"">{1}</a>", workflowguid, ItemRow["Title"].ToString());
```

in code using "SPContext.Current.Web.Url" will show SPContext.Current.Web.Url but if you do it outside of the "" than it will show http://Mysite.com

but dont you mean to use `SPContext.Current.Site`

```
strng.Format(@"<a href="""" "+SPContext.Current.Site+"/_layouts/something/Mypage.aspx?workflowID={0}"+"\"\""+">{1}</a>", workflowguid, ItemRow["Title"].ToString());
```

Comment: it now shows http://Mysite.com but still some "" are missing at the end.. Can u check it again?

Comment: can you copy past the result? so i know where its missing!

Comment: it shows red underline near: ">{1}</a>", workflowguid, ItemRow

Comment: ok iv just editited the answer, copy paste the bottom example :) , iv added \ after each double quote to say its a litral double quote to be displayed :)

Comment: still not correct... ?? whol is redunderlined now..?

Comment: For every "something" you need a + to bind it to another "something"

The Pattern should be `""+""+""`

Comment: now try it again iv changed and tested it myself this time and its working :)

Comment: @mike the issue was he wanted double double quotes, so for the first part to show a double double quote i had to do "" "" and at the end i had to add the + \" as it didnt like the double double method!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/267k4fw5.aspx

Comment: yes i understand that, if you were to make a console app and copy paste the code and put that in it doesnt work hence the solution I gave as it gives the desired result :) , for some reason it doesnt like \" on both ends as that was my first solution and had to change it to """" and ""\"\""

Comment: it works now...

Comment: good :) , i had to test it myself just to make sure ;)